# Docker: How does this (not) work?

Tags: docker, boot2docker, mysql

I am trying to create a docker image which runs an sql server. For this purpose I did the following steps on a Windows machine.

1. Run a mysql container to copy an init file into the virtual machine (not sure whether this step is actually necessary):

   ```
   docker run -i centurylink/mysql /bin/bash -c 'cat > table.sql' < /c/Users/bastian/Documents/docker/table.sql
   ```
2. Create an image from the resulting container:

   ```
   docker commit ID mysql/with-table
   ```
3. Run the image in order to initialize the database:

   ```
   docker run -d -it -p 3306:3306 -v /c/Users/bastian/Documents/docker/mysql:/mysql -e MYSQL_DATABASE='google' -e MYSQL_USER='foo' -e MYSQL_PASSWORD='bar' MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='xxx' mysql/with-table
   ```

Now I have the follwing questions:

1. When I execute `docker inspect ID3` the output contains the command:

   ```
   "Cmd": [
        "/bin/bash",
        "-c",
        "cat \u003e table.sql"
    ]
   ```

   Does this mean that the copy command is executed and not the mysql server? How do I see which command will actually be executed?
2. If I try to connect to the mysql server on the host machine:

   ```
   $ boot2docker ip 2> /dev/null
   192.168.59.103

   $ mysql -h 192.168.59.103 -p 3306
   Enter password: ***                        // I enter xxx here
   ```

   I get the following error message:

   ```
   ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.59.103' (10061)
   ```

   Any idea what the reason might be?

EDIT: So, I just removed the first steps and instead ran the centurylink/mysql image directly. If I do this and change the mysql line to `$ mysql -h 192.168.59.103 -p -u root` (or `-u foo`) the connection works. Thus, the mysql line is erroneous and the mysql server is actually not started correctly when steps 1 and 2 are performed. Do you know the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a container with `docker run some_image some_command`, you've given it a command to run.  In your case (step 1) this command was `/bin/bash -c 'cat > table.sql'`.  Then in step 2 you committed that command to a new image. So your image runs that command instead of mysql.

Maybe look at `docker exec` to do the futzing around to initialize.  Or mount the data as a '[Docker Volume](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/)'.